# Magento2 convert html to either array or json

Tags: magento2, html, json

Magento2 How can I convert html ul li list that I got from CMS block into Json or array format?

Can someone please guide me on that?

Answer (score 1):

Try Like this :

```
$string = '<ul><li>Coffee</li><li>Tea</li><li>Milk</li></ul>';
$dom = new \DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($string);
$array = [];
foreach($dom->getElementsByTagName('li') as $node) {
    $array[] = $node->textContent;
}
echo "<pre>";print_r($array);
```

Results :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Coffee
    [1] => Tea
    [2] => Milk
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use php dom document

```
$string = '
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
  <li>Milk</li>
';

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($string);

foreach($dom->getElementsByTagName('li') as $node)
{
    $array[] = $dom->saveHTML($node);
}

print_r($array);
```

Comment: Error: Class 'XYZ\TopHeaderMenuAPI\Model\DOMDocument' not found in

Comment: php-dom php-xml need to be enabled in your server

Comment: installed them both still not working

Answer (score 0):

> **Try This Code**

```
<?php

$string = '
<ul>
  <li>Coffee 0</li>
  <li>Tea 0</li>
  <li>Milk 0</li>
 </ul>
 <ul>
  <li>Coffee 1</li>
  <li>Tea 1</li>
  <li>Milk 1</li>
 </ul>
';

function tag_contents($string, $tag_open, $tag_close){
   foreach (explode($tag_open, $string) as $key => $value) {
       if(strpos($value, $tag_close) !== FALSE){
            $result[] = substr($value, 0, strpos($value, $tag_close));;
       }
   }
   return $result;
}

echo "<pre>";
$ulExtractData = tag_contents($string, '<ul>', '</ul>');
foreach ($ulExtractData as $ulExtractKey => $ulExtractVal) {
    echo "***  UL Data ".$ulExtractKey."   ***<br/>";
    echo "<br/>Array Data :- <br/>";
    print_r(tag_contents($ulExtractVal, '<li>', '</li>'));  
    echo "<br/>Json Data :- <br/>";
    print_r(json_encode(tag_contents($ulExtractVal, '<li>', '</li>'))); 
    echo "<br/>";
    echo "<br/>";
}   
echo "</pre>";
```